# PHP Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]

Tags: php, filemtime

I've noticed that the directory on which one of the PHP script is installed have very large error_log file almost of 1GB size, mostly the errors are generated by coding on line 478 and 479.. example of the error from error_log file is below:

```
PHP Warning:  filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for /home/khan/public_html/folder/ZBall.jar in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 478
PHP Warning:  filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for /home/khan/public_html/folder/ZBall.jar in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 479
```

I have the following coding, line 477 to 484

```
foreach ($mp3s as $gftkey => $gftrow) {
   $ftimes[$gftkey] = array(filemtime($thecurrentdir.$gftrow),$gftrow);
   $ftimes2[$gftkey] = filemtime($thecurrentdir.$gftrow);
 }
 array_multisort($ftimes2,SORT_DESC,$ftimes);
 foreach ($ftimes as $readd) {
   $newmp3s[] = $readd[1];
 }
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `stat failed` error would indicate that the file `/home/khan/public_html/games/ZBall.jar` either doesn't exist, or can't be read due to a permission error.  Make sure the file exists in the place PHP is looking, as that seems like the most like cause of the problem.

Since it comes from the array `$mp3s`, make sure that array contains names of files that exist and modify it if not.

Comment: well the file does exist and also the file gets downloaded, there is no issue at front-end.. problem is error_log file is generated and as the files are downloaded in large number the file size gets bigger and bigger.. have applied @Gabriel Sosa edited code.. hope it would work.. :-)

Comment: After applying @Gabriel Sosa's the following error is generated...   <br/>`PHP Warning: array_multisort() [<a href='function.array-multisort'>function.array-multisort</a>]: Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 483 PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 484`  <br/>
Code from line 483-486  <br/> `array_multisort($ftimes2,SORT_DESC,$ftimes); foreach ($ftimes as $readd) { $newmp3s[] = $readd[1]; }`

<br />
Any kind of help would be appreciated.. Thanks..

Comment: @HaroonKhattak Your problem is not that you have a growing error log, it is that your code is producing errors.  Something is preventing Apache/PHP from being able to stat that file.

Comment: @HaroonKhattak That new error looks to be because the array `$ftimes2` is not created. If `file_exists()` returns false, as it will when that file isn't found (per the stat error), your array will never be built, and will error when passed to `array_multisort()`

Comment: well i've added absolute path as read on forum that filemtime on some systems doesn't work unless you specify the absolute path instead of the relative path.. lets see..

 `foreach ($mp3s as $gftkey => $gftrow) {
    if (file_exists($thecurrentdir.$gftrow)) {
   $ftimes[$gftkey] = array(filemtime('/home/khan/public_html/folder/' . $thecurrentdir.$gftrow),$gftrow);
   $ftimes2[$gftkey] = array(filemtime('/home/khan/public_html/folder/' . $thecurrentdir.$gftrow),$gftrow);
    }
  }
  array_multisort($ftimes2,SORT_DESC,$ftimes);
  foreach ($ftimes as $readd) {
    $newmp3s[] = $readd[1];
 }`

Answer (score 1):

ask for the file before doing something with it. checm my edit:

```
<?php
foreach ($mp3s as $gftkey => $gftrow) {
   if (file_exists($thecurrentdir.$gftrow)) {
     $ftimes[$gftkey] = array(filemtime($thecurrentdir.$gftrow),$gftrow);
     $ftimes2[$gftkey] = filemtime($thecurrentdir.$gftrow);
   }
 }
 array_multisort($ftimes2,SORT_DESC,$ftimes);
 foreach ($ftimes as $readd) {
   $newmp3s[] = $readd[1];
 }
```

Comment: i've added your edited code, site is working.. so far no error_log file is created in that folder.. will let u know if any error is generated.. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: Now this error is generated...

`PHP Warning:  array_multisort() [<a href='function.array-multisort'>function.array-multisort</a>]: Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 483
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/khan/public_html/folder/index.php on line 484`

Code from line 483-486
  `array_multisort($ftimes2,SORT_DESC,$ftimes);
  foreach ($ftimes as $readd) {
    $newmp3s[] = $readd[1];
 }`

Comment: if the foreach is throwing that, looks like none of your files exists, so the last foreach is trying to iterate over a non-existent array. check the path of the files, and if you like accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function on PHP.net site which removes a bug on Windows about `filemtime`

```
function GetCorrectMTime($filePath) { 

$time = filemtime($filePath); 

$isDST = (date('I', $time) == 1); 
$systemDST = (date('I') == 1); 

$adjustment = 0; 

if($isDST == false && $systemDST == true) 
    $adjustment = 3600; 

else if($isDST == true && $systemDST == false) 
    $adjustment = -3600; 

else 
    $adjustment = 0; 

return ($time + $adjustment); 
}
```

source: `http://php.net/manual/tr/function.filemtime.php#100692`